# Endpoint that is locked down with hasIpAddress requires "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have two different means of security.

1. is locked down with an IP check, and only an IP check, I do not care about further authentication.
2. is a role check where I want to authenticate with a resource server and validate the token.

With the code I have, the role check is working as expected. I get a 200, 401, and 403 correctly. This issue is when I try to hit the endpoint that does the IP check, I get an error of

> Full authentication is required to access this resourceunauthorized

I only want to perform an IP address check.

### LOGS

```
Checking match of request : '/locked'; against '\/locked'
Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /locked; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(hasIpAddress('192.168.216.0/23') or hasIpAddress('10.4.7.59'))]
Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@c36755eb: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@40adb6a3, returned: -1
Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
```

### Code

(Spring Boot 2.2.2)

```java
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "whitelist", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
public class EnabledSecurityConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String ESIGN_PURGE_BATCH = "ESIGN_PURGE_BATCH";

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .httpBasic().disable();
        http
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
            .csrf().disable();

        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .regexMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "\\/locked").access("hasIpAddress('192.168.216.0/23') or hasIpAddress('10.4.7.59')")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/purgePackets").hasRole(ESIGN_PURGE_BATCH)
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

```
 implementation("org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.2.2.RELEASE")
```

then in my properties I set (But this works for the role check as mentioned)

```
security.oauth2.resource.jwk.key-set-uri=https://ourOauthserver.com/uaa/oauth/token_keys
```

Comment: @BradenBorman Also you are testing with the wrong IP address: *RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1* You have to test from the machine with `192.168.216.0/23` or `'10.4.7.59`. And you have to use these IP addresses or the DNS name in your URL.

Comment: You were correct, once I updated it to check for '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1' I was able to access things as expected. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

The answer in my case was the wrong IP address for testing. You do not want to use the IP that the provider assigns, instead the local IP that I should be using, which was

> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1

Spring does NOT provide a log that says IPs failed to match, and so when it said "Full Authentication is needed" I just ASSUMED it was doing more than I wanted and getting passed the IP.